# grpcurl call from Kubernetes cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob, grpcurl

I have a grpc service running in Kubernetes. I need a Kubernetes cronjob to invoke this service using grpcurl command.
My Kubernetes cronjob yaml file looks as mentioned bellow.

When I run this cronjob in kubernetes, I receive "/bin/sh: grpcurl: not found" error.
How should I Install/get access to grpcurl for my kubernetes cronjob?

Comment: Use an image that has gpcurl installed in it , busybox doesn't have it.

Comment: do you mean, I will have to create a new image with preinstalled grpcurl? Sorry for the noob level question. I am new to all this.

Comment: Yes , i tried building one but i couldnot find how to install grpccurl , if you point me to steps i can try else go with some other image that you think will have it.

Comment: this documentation points to installation step. https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install grpcurl in busybox or better Make a dockerfile with grpccurl.
You can also use an image with grpccurl already installed

I have made a sample image `tarrunkhosla/grpcio:v1`

Try using this in your YAML.

Comment: It has helped me.... I dont know how do i accept your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.